# Building Navigation Items from Categories Table in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Categories table that has the following structure

```
Categories Table
----------------
id
name
slug
```

I want to build a navigation bar based on the table's content.

**Current Implementation**

1. I have a private method in the ApplicationController

   ```
   private
     def get_categories
       @categories = Category.all
     end
   ```
2. I have the following before_action

   ```
   before_action :get_categories
   ```
3. I use the `@categories` instance variable to build my navigation bar.

**Problem**

This use of `before_action` does not seem right here. It's not really a filter method. Is there a better/different approach to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a helper method for that and used directly in the views. Also you can use caching if your categories doesn't change frequently.

Comment: I guess, I could define the helper method right in the ApplicationController by using helper_method :get_categories. Would that be an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 0):

As you want to use `Category.all` for creating navigation bar which is a presentation part it would be better to create a helper for creating navigation bar if there is some logic involved in construction of navigation bar. In the helper method you can directly use `Categories.all`

If you just want to create a navigation bar which do not have logic involved and just want to iterate our categories, I would suggest you to use `Category.all` directly on views. But make sure that in future you wouldn't be adding any logic for creation of navigation bar.
If you follow above method and in future decide to add few scope to Category depending on user or other factors, then you would have to modify all the places where 'Category.all' is used for creation of navigation bar. This won't be a problem if navigation bar is just created from just one view file.

The choice of writing code in controller or helper depends on how you would be `Category.all` on view. If `Category.all` needs to be used only once in a view to iterate over Category it would be nice to directly use `Category.all` on views.